# Как сделать так чтобы картинка в блоке исчезала после того как человек доходит до этого блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок с картинкой, оно должно исчезнуть после того как до него дойдут и вместо него должны появиться другие блоки. Как можно сделать?

Comment: http://scrollmagic.io/

Comment: а ваш код можно, что вы пытаетесь сделать